# CSS / JS slider transition effect

Tags: javascript, css

I recently came across a slider on this website - https://antoni.de/. I really like the transition effect but I can't for the life of me figure out how it's done. I get how the slider works but its the actual transition that is baffling me. I have no idea what this effect is called and I am not sure if it is done by CSS or JS? Would love to be able to imitate the same sort of transition effect. Does anyone know how this done and can point me in the right direction to building something similar?

This is an image of the transition effect: 
[image]

Comment: inspect code, check JS library, check CSS, contact site owner, etc etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have done that but still can't figure it out.

Comment: That is HTML5/WebGL and most likely a video plug-in with some text overlay. There are some JS libraries that will easily allow you to implement these effects very easily. [Check this](http://vodkabears.github.io/vide/) as an example.

Comment: It's a Wordpress site. The source code URLs show plenty of `/wp-content/uploads` links. Therefore this awesome effect is most likely a Wordpress plugin.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thank you for your comment. I have looked into it using WordPress scanning sites to see if I can find the plugin but nothing shows up. I believe it is a totally custom built theme.

Answer (score 1):

Its made with canvas HTML5, you can see this in source code.

Answer (score 0):

I actually messaged the developer to find out how he made this. It is made using webGL!